# Authorization error with google plus sign in

Tags: ruby, oauth-2.0, sinatra, google-plus

I'm using the google plus [ruby quickstart](https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-ruby) to add "sign in with google" to a small sinatra application. I am able to successfully request the authorization code client side, but the request to exchange the code for a token fails. I've replaced *all* of my application's code with the code in the example repo, but I receive the same error.

```
# received the authorization code
# exchange it for a token 
$authorization.fetch_access_token!
```

**Error**

```
Signet::AuthorizationError - Authorization failed.  Server message:
{
  "error" : "invalid_request",
  "error_description" : "Required parameter is missing: grant_type"
}
```

I know that things are failing inside [signet](https://github.com/google/signet/blob/f8fd709c811554d146d001fc088e7f8d8ce3882b/lib/signet/oauth_2/client.rb#L928) but i'm not sure how to inspect the request to see what is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to set the grant_type to the refresh_token before you fetch the token from google?

I've used the same client in a rails app and shimming the grant_type into the signet auth object works.

```
client.authorization.grant_type = 'refresh_token'
client.authorization.fetch_access_token!

=> {"access_token"=>"foo", "token_type"=>"Bearer", "expires_in"=>3600, "id_token"=>"foo"}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll accept this and report back when I get a chance to look at the project.